# Javascript conflicting with eachover

Tags: javascript, html

I have two pieces of java script, one for showing the result percentage in a progress bar, one to show the speed in a different bar.

at the moment only one bar is reviving data the other is not.

**Javascript*

```
//  Progress bar javascript reults
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
        var width = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

        function frame() {
            if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2").innerHTML) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
            }
        }
    }

    // End javascript progress bar results

    // Progress bar javascript speed
    {
        var elem = document.getElementById("myBarspeed");
        var width = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

        function frame() {
            if (width >= document.getElementById("results-speed").innerHTML) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                width++;
                elem.style.width = width + '%';
                document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
            }
        }
    }

    // End javascript progress bar speed
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="scale-container-main ">
                        <div id="percentile-scale" class="scale">

                            results bar: Your results
                            <div id="demo">0%</div>
                            <div class="myProgress">
                                <div id="myBar" style="width:0"></div>
                            </div>

                            speed bar: Your speed
                            <div id="speed">0%</div>
                            <div class="myProgress">
                                <div id="myBarspeed" style="width:0"></div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: That JS is invalid

Comment: you're clobbering the frame function and the var's - those two blocks are not isolated scopes - javascript isn't like c++ - unless you use `let` instead of `var` in modern browsers (that means you can forget IE)

Comment: @Liam - it's valid, just not good

Comment: @JaromandaX, how would i make this work correctly to work on IE

Comment: as an alternative to the answer below, you could enclose the two blocks in separate IIFE's ... i.e. `(function()` { ... your code ...} `());`

Comment: Ok, that seems to make scene, Ill give this a go. then update my question with this. thanks

Comment: why would you update the question? the point is to keep the incorrect code in the question for others who come across the same problem, not change your question to have correct code so nobody knows what the question even was

Comment: Ok, I got you. Thanks for your help. Ill leave the question and accept your answer

Comment: It's a pet peeve but it's called `Javascript`. Notice the `t` on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `let` instead of var inside each block, and

```
let frame = function() { .... }
```

but frame would have to be moved above setInterval line

Also, the above only works on recent decent broswers, which means it wont work in IE

An alternative, equally valid method is to use IIFE's - this works in IE!

```
(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= document.getElementById("results-percentile-2").innerHTML) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}());

// End javascript progress bar results

// Progress bar javascrip speed
(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBarspeed");
    var width = 0;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

    function frame() {
        if (width >= document.getElementById("results-speed").innerHTML) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
    }
}());
```

The only advantage to the above is that variable names can be useful and meaningful and guaranteed not to clash with anything else (sort of)

Comment: Hmm immediately invoked function, Ok +1 for not only a working answer but for helping me improve and understand javascrip. Im still trying to improve mt javascript and this has helped a lot, thanks you.

Comment: In regards to using let, would this be more efficient ?

Comment: efficient? it's more "modern" but I wouldn't know about efficient (I don't benchmark to the nth degree myself) - the problem at the moment is the pervasiveness of Internet Explorer, which means we must code for the lowest common denominator ... if you want to write modern code that still runs almost everywhere, look at things like [babel](http://babeljs.io/)

Comment: balbel, ok im dealing with lots of legacy js atm im slowly working through, i was thinking typescript but ill look at balbel

Comment: babel allows you to use modern javascript techniques defined in ES2015/ES6+ cross browser - it "transpiles" to javascript for dummies :p I mean for older browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two functions with the same name. Rename one 'frame' function to something else and change it in your setInterval. Also use different variables to store the interval in.

Comment: hmm, even after the function name change still dose not work

Comment: because there's variables that are the same as well